# What is the best way to get string column from a Pandas Dataframe into a TensorFLow model?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

So lets say I have some Pandas DataFrames that contain some string columns:

```
Animal  Name    Age  ...
Cat     Fluffy  2    ...
Dog     Denton  3    ...
```

And I want to input the Animal column (with a know set of values) into my training model (for Linear Regression). I looked at the following options:

1. `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` but then it appears you use it with `tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec` and protocol buffers.
2. `tf.one_hot` sounded like it might help but the example code really didn't help me understand.

Or should I just be writing something myself to convert the strings into numeric/Boolean data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.feature_column.input_layer` function to create an input tensor. First, the categorical column must be wrapped as an indicator or embedding column.

Example:

```
# Create columns
vocab_list = ['a','b','c','d']
letter_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    key="letter",
    vocabulary_list=vocab_list)
embedded_column = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(letter_column, 8)
indicator_column = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(letter_column)

# Create features and use input_layer to get a tensor
features = {'letter': ['c']}
inp = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features,[embedded_column, indicator_column])

# Print value of inp
with tf.Session() as s:
  s.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(),
         tf.local_variables_initializer(),
         tf.tables_initializer()])
  print(s.run(inp))
```

Output (first 8 numbers may vary):

```
[[ 0.29994071 -0.07036652 -0.23166095  0.0681599  -0.07477489 -0.25384274
  -0.31568974 -0.09161812  0.          0.          1.          0.        ]]
```

`inp` is a tensor with 12 elements. The first 8 is the embedding calculated from `embedded_column` (which is trainable), and the last 4 are a multi-hot representation of the value from `indicator_column`.

Answer (score 0):

The tf.feature_column namespace can be ignored as follows:

Use pandas to automatically encode your string columns into numerical values. The category columns in your original dataframe will have a property **cat.codes**. You can create a new pandas column and copy those cat.codes into it. The new column will be a numerical column and filled with the numbers you need for neural networks.

Use code like this to find the category columns, and create the new columns:

```
str_cols = [cn for cn in d.columns if is_string_dtype(d[cn])]
add_code_columns = [cn for cn in d.columns if (cn in cat_cols) and (cn in str_cols)]

for cn in add_code_columns:
  codecolname = cn + "_code"
  if not codecolname in d.columns:
    d[codecolname] = d[cn].cat.codes
```